# Can't get Artifactory loaded on Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, artifactory

I can't get Artifactory working in Docker with MySQL. Below is the error I get.

I first create a place to persist Artifactory's files:

`# sudo mkdir /opt/artifactory/docker_volume`

Setting up a compose file using an external MySQL instance (using a stack instance didn't work, either, as the stack instance never spun up).

artifactory-oss-mysql.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  artifactory:
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:6.1.0
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - /opt/artifactory/docker_volume:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
      - /opt/artifactory/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar
    environment:
      - DB_TYPE=mysql
      - DB_USER=artifactory
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_PASSWORD=xxx
      - DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://my_sql:3306/artdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8&elideSetAutoCommits=true
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 32000
        hard: 40000
```

Starting the stack:

`# docker stack deploy -c artifactory-oss-mysql.yml artifactory`

You'll notice that the `docker_volume` owner has changed, along with everything underneat it.  The only exception is the mysql connector (`/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar`), which retains root ownership.

```
# ls -al
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    4096 Jul 17 17:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    4096 Jul 17 15:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 1030 1030    4096 Jul 17 17:47 docker_volume
```

Every subdirectory is empty (except for the connector in tomcat):

```
/opt/artifactory/docker_volume # ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 8 1030 1030 4096 Jul 17 17:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 17 17:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 1030 1030 4096 Jul 17 17:47 access
drwxr-xr-x 2 1030 1030 4096 Jul 17 17:47 backup
drwxr-xr-x 2 1030 1030 4096 Jul 17 17:47 data
drwxr-xr-x 2 1030 1030 4096 Jul 17 17:47 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 1030 1030 4096 Jul 17 17:47 logs
drwxr-xr-x 3 1030 1030 4096 Jul 17 17:47 tomcat
```

`# docker service logs zh3fiophtdvu`

```
    Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
=====================================
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [44 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Dockerfile for this image can found inside the container.
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [45 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] To view the Dockerfile: 'cat /docker/artifactory-oss/Dockerfile.artifactory'.
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [50 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking open files and processes limits
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [53 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Current max open files is 1048576
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [65 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Current max open processes is unlimited
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [75 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking if /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is mounted
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [80 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is mounted
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [86 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Setting up data directories if missing
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [97 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Create artifactory user if missing
2018-07-17 21:13:06  [100 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] User does not exist. Creating it...
2018-07-17 21:13:06  [137 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking permissions on /opt/jfrog/artifactory
2018-07-17 21:13:06  [143 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /opt/jfrog/artifactory is owned by root:root. Setting to artifactory:artifactory.
2018-07-17 21:13:06  [150 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking permissions on /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
2018-07-17 21:13:06  [159 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is already owned by artifactory:artifactory.
2018-07-17 21:13:06  [282 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking DB_TYPE
2018-07-17 21:13:06  [285 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] DB_TYPE is set to mysql
2018-07-17 21:13:06   [34 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] ERROR: No mysql connector found
```

Comment: Change location of MySql driver jar to `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following to better understand and solve your problem:

- remove `ulimits.nofile` section
- `chown -R 1030:1030` for your required volumes

It seems a permission issue.